# How to wait on answer from multiple Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a `Router` class in Java and in that class I am implementing the "[Distance Vector Routing Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol)".
In this protocol there is a place in the code where I am waiting on a response from all my neighbor `Routers` before continuing the protocol.
I am preforming the connection to other routers using the TCP/IP protocol and using the [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) Classes.
The issue I am having is understanding how to halt my main code from running until I have received a reply from all my neighbor `Routers`.
So my question is this:
Given an array of Sockets who are sending messages to other routers, how do I halt the code until all Routers have received a reply?
Example:

```
neighbor_amount = 10
Socket [] sockets = new Sockets[neighbor_amount]
for (int i=1; i<neighbor_amount; i++){
    sockets[i] = new Socket (some_neighbor_ip, some_neighbor_port)
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(sockets[i].getOutputStream());  
    dout.writeUTF("Give me Info");  
    dout.flush();  
}
// How to tell code to stop here until all Sockets in the array have received reply with info?
```

Comment: Each socket must be handled by its own thread. While the socket threads are waiting for the neighbors' responses, the main thread can create a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and wait for the count to become 0. When the socket threads receive their responses, they decrement the count down.

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer?